# Error 404 during GWT RPC jetty server

Tags: gwt, rpc

I just written simple RPC call, when i tried i get the below error, could you please help me out to fix this..

```
[WARN] 404 - POST /com.sribalajiele.gwt.client.SriBalajiEle/emailRpcService (127.0.0.1) 
Email Failure404 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
```

The code like below.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Balaji electricals AG 2011, All Rights Reserved
 */
package com.sribalajiele.gwt.client.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

/**
 * @author kdel.
 * This interface provides Email Service.
 *
 */
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("emailRpcService")
public interface EmailRpcService extends RemoteService {

   public WriteToUsForm sendEmail(WriteToUsForm writeToUsForm) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}


/*
 * Copyright (c) Balaji electricals 2011, All Rights Reserved
 */
package com.sribalajiele.gwt.client.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

/**
 * @author kdel
 * Async service for Email.
 */
public interface EmailRpcServiceAsync {
   void sendEmail(WriteToUsForm writeToUsForm, AsyncCallback<WriteToUsForm> asyncCallback)
   throws IllegalArgumentException;
}


public final class EmailRpcServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements EmailRpcService {

   /**
    * Default serialVersionUID.
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public WriteToUsForm sendEmail(WriteToUsForm writeToUsForm) throws IllegalArgumentException  {  
          System.out.println("send Email called");
    }
}
```

In `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>emailService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sribalajiele.gwt.client.server.EmailRpcServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>emailService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>sriBalajiEle/emailRpcService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If you post some of your code, it'll be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply.. i have added some code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Finally i could correct my self, may be this is use full for others.

1) @RemoteServiceRelativePath("emailRpcService")
public interface EmailRpcService extends RemoteService {

2) In *Module*.gwt.xml
<servlet class="com.sribalajiele.ui.server.EmailRpcServiceImpl" path="/emailRpcService"/>

3) Register your servlet in web.xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>eamilService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sribalajiele.ui.server.EmailRpcServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>eamilService</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/com.sribalajiele.ui.SriBalaji/emailRpcService</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>

4) Usage:

  final EmailRpcServiceAsync emailRpcServiceAsync = (EmailRpcServiceAsync) GWT.create(EmailRpcService.class);
      ServiceDefTarget serviceDef = (ServiceDefTarget) emailRpcServiceAsync;
      serviceDef.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "emailRpcService");
emailRpcServiceAsync.sendEmail(parameter, new AsyncCall()) {
onSuccess() { }
onFailure() { }
}
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: Also in case it's of use to others: I ran across the HTTP 404 issue, but my configuration was all correct. Turns out I needed to re-launch (rather than just refresh) the debug session in order to get the servlet running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the servlet mapped to `/sriBalajiEle/emailRpcService`, but the request is being sent to `/com.sribalajiele.gwt.client.SriBalajiEle/emailRpcService`. The URL that the request is being sent to is generated by GWT in the form `/${moduleName}/relativePath`. If you include the following at the top of your GWT module, it should fix the 404.

```
<module rename-to="sriBalajiEle">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added already the above line but still have the same issue, could you please let me know is there any other place where i need to add/configure this. thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you could change your `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml` to use the `<url-pattern>` `com.sribalajiele.gwt.client.SriBalajiEle/emailRpcService`

Comment: I have tried this, but still i could not get it.. have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Include annotatation in your interface too.

> ```
> @RemoteServiceRelativePath("emailRpcService")
> public interface EmailRpcServiceAsync {
>    void sendEmail(WriteToUsForm writeToUsForm,
> ```
>
> AsyncCallback asyncCallback)
>          throws IllegalArgumentException;
>       }

2) And change your url mapping to the following.

```
    <url-pattern>com.sribalajiele.gwt.EmailRpcService/emailRpcService</url-pattern>
```

For my case, url mapping gave me headache for hours. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the 404 error will site a url, I had to make sure the url sited in the 404 message was the url in my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>messageServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/com.mbe.site.main/message</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```